# How to open multiple files using arguments from windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I know how to open an external application within a windows forms application and a file using an argument. Is there a way to pass multiple argument to open more than one file at a time. At the moment file2 simply overwrites file1. Im using Visual Studio 2017 windows forms C#, thanks.

```
                    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    startInfo.FileName = (app + ".exe");
                    startInfo.Arguments = file1;
                    startInfo.Arguments = file2;
                    Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Put them into one `string` and separate them with spaces. e.g. with `$"{file1} {file2}"`

Comment: Perfect. Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It very much depends on the application you're launching. Does it support opening multiple files via command line? You would have to check its command line arguments.

If you made the other application, you can pass multiple arguments to the `Arguments` property by separating them with spaces. Note that you'll also have to put them in quotes if there are spaces in their paths.

So to launch the application you would do something like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = (app + ".exe");
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", file1, file2);
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

and then in the other application, you have your Main method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     // args[0] contains file1
     // args[1] contains file2
}
```

Comment: It was for opening two files in winmerge.  Biesi Grr answered my question but since i cant vote on a comment ill except your answer.